# References Assemblies for .Net framework version not found Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

The aspx files for my website are giving the error: "References Assemblies for .Net framework version not found; please ensure they are installed, or select a valid target version." In my web.config file I am using .net framework 4.5.2, which is installed on my machine. When I view my website in a browser, it does not load any style sheets, instead displaying a directory of the pages. What would be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open IIS Manager. Wnd+R type inetmgr
- On the Connections pane, expand the server node and click Application Pools.
- On the Application Pools page, select the application pool for which you want to specify a .NET Framework version, and then click Basic Settings in the Actions pane.
- In the Edit Application Pool dialog box, in the .NET Framework version list, select the version that you want the application pool to use or select No Managed Code if the application uses only native code.
- Click OK.